# Issue configuring puppetlabs/apache module with Vagrant

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I started using Vagrant and Puppet recently, and i am having bit of difficulty getting puppet to work.

With puppet i want to change apache user and group to vagrant to solve permission issue when sharing the folder.

I want to do it by using following puppet config

```
class { "apache":
    user => "vagrant",
    group => "vagrant",
}
```

Reference : http://ryansechrest.com/2014/04/unable-set-permissions-within-shared-folder-using-vagrant-virtualbox/

For this i installed puppet on my host and guest machine, on host machine i added following cofig in Vagrantfile

```
config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = 'puppet/manifests'
    puppet.module_path    = 'puppet/modules'
end
```

And created the file puppet/manifests/default.pp on host machine with following content

```
node 'node1' {

    include apache

    class { "apache":
        user => "vagrant",
        group => "vagrant",
    }
}
```

When i run vagrant provision, i get the following error

```
==> default: Error: Could not find default node or by name with 'localhost' on node localhost
==> default: Error: Could not find default node or by name with 'localhost' on node localhost
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep it simple:

> For this i installed puppet on my host and guest machine,

you only need puppet to be installed on your guest machine, you can keep your host clean

you reference and define `puppet/manifests/default.pp` which is fine, just remove the node part

```
Package {
  allow_virtual => true,
}

class { "apache":
    user => "vagrant",
    group => "vagrant",
}

include apache
```

can you confirm you have an `apache` module in your host `puppet/modules` or installed on the guest - you can have provision to run something like

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /etc/puppet/modules;

if [ ! -d /etc/puppet/modules/puppetlabs-apache ]; then
  puppet module install puppetlabs-apache
fi
```

assuming you talk about [this apache](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/apache) module, else replace with the module you're using if it comes from the forge

Comment: I have the module installed, I got it to work a while ago, however it gives me some notices saying few syntaxes are deprecated, is it normal?

Comment: oh right, might need to add this `allow_virtual => true` thing, editing my answer, it should pass ok like this